# Unable to connect to AWS ubuntu instance by using VNC after creating AMI

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, vnc

I have an Ubuntu instance that I can use ssh(22 port) and vnc(5901~5909) to connect to this instance.
After installing nginx for my application,then I create AMI for backup.
However,I cannot connect to this instance by using VNC after creating AMI ,but using ssh still works.
Does anyone have similar experience? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does the security group look like?

Comment: I set TCP 22port source 0.0.0.0/0 for ssh,and customize TCP 5901 source 0.0.0.0/0 for VNC